# Has this patent been approved?

Tags: claims, application, infringement

In reference to the patent: [US20020043764](https://www.google.com/patents/US20020043764)

Has this patent application been reviewed and registered? I cannot find that information. The assignee is stating it has been, but I have yet to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to tell: any US patent application ends with "A".  So, in this case, US 20020043764 A1 means that reference is being made to an application.  Now, this might refer to an application that will never become a patent, perhaps because it was abandoned for some reason.  However, if you see a US patent number that ends in "B", you know the patent actually issued.

Refer to http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/electronic-business-center/kind-codes-included-uspto-patent, for more information.

To actually determine current status of the patent application, you will need to refer, as the other answer points out, check the status of a US patent at the Public PAIR system.

Answer (score 0):

No, this application will not become a patent. The application went abandoned on 09-08-2003.

You can find information regarding the status of a US application from the [Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) system.

Comment: There may be the possibility of continuations, etc.

Comment: @ShaunHinds This link to another similar question on the site might help with interpreting the data from PAIR: [Understanding PAIR](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/13635/is-this-an-approved-patent/13638#13638)