# Is this an approved patent?

Tags: patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [WO2008150815A2](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2008150815A2)

Answer (score 1):

Try the Public Pair search from the patent office.
Search with this number: PCT/US08/65008

That number is the application number, and not the reference number (as you have given us in your question above).
Data is listed from most recent to earilest.

- 06-06-2008 **Notification of Intntl. Appl. Number and Intntl. Filing**

  This lets the applicant know that it has been assgined an *Application* number.

  However, since the information trail stops here, so it looks like the patent in question is still regarded as a application and not a "patent".
- 06-06-2008 **Notification Concerning Payment of Fees**

  This means: filer was asked to pay fees associated with filing the patent.
- 06-06-2008 **Record Copy Mailed**

  A copy of the patent application was mailed to the applicant.
- 05-30-2008 **Cleared by OIPE CSR**

  That means: Approved by Office of Initial Patent Examination Customer Service Representative
- 05-28-2008 **Receipt Date**

  According to the patent office that means:

  > (a) Date of receipt and Priority Mail Express® date of deposit. Correspondence received in the Patent and Trademark Office is stamped with the date.
- 05-28-2008 **IFW Scan & PACR Auto Security**

  Image File Wrapper -- an electronic version of a patent application.

  Patent advisory committee representative automatically checked for problems. There were none and the process continued.
- 05-28-2008 **Initial Exam Team nn**

  This means: patent application revived.

Comment: If possible, could you please [edit] your answer here to include a bit more about how this information is useful in answering the asker's question? We'd like to start using this as a canonical question and answer to point users to when they ask about PCT applications, so we want to make sure this has enough information that someone with minimal knowledge in the field could benefit from it. It's up to you whether you'd like to do so, but I would appreciate it, and I'm sure other readers would as well! :)

Comment: @MatthewHaugen , Take a look at the new update. -TZ122

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I modified the formatting a bit, feel free to clean it up more if there's anything you see.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, and more simply, from the "A1" at the end you know it remains an application and has not been granted.  "A" is called the "kind code" and tells you the status of the underlying patent.

See here, for a short page about WIPO kind codes:
http://worldwide.espacenet.com/help?locale=en_EP&method=handleHelpTopic&topic=kindcodes

I actually think the USPTO has a better page (again referring to their use of WIPO kind codes) here:
http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/electronic-business-center/kind-codes-included-uspto-patent